# Add label to matrix column

Tags: r

I have a data matrix M and a column vector L of labels. I want to add the column vector to the matrix via:

```
   M = cbind(L,M)
```

But now I want to give that column vector (ie the 1st col in M) the label 'Gene'. How do I do this?

The reason is....I want to do the same process with a second matrix P and then merge M and P based on 'Gene' using something like

```
merge(M, P, by="Gene", all=TRUE)
```

Comment: You mention "matrix". Is your object really a `matrix` or is it a `data.frame`?

Comment: For `merge` there is also option of `by.x` and `by.y`.

Comment: Try `cbind(Gene=L,M)`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys! My object is actually a data frame.

cbind(Gene=L,M) works well but I'm now struggling with the merging bit.

How do I use the by.x and by.y options to merge the 2 objects based on common Gene labels?